# After deleting xml nodes in java ,xml file doesnt get update

Tags: java, xml

I am using following code to remove some specific nodes from xml file..It show correct output on console
but somehow xml file is not getting updated..the contents remains as it is..
please help..
Thanks...

```
package com.sumit.xml.client;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat;
import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*; 
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class ReadCDATA {
  static public void main(String[] arg) {
  try{
  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.print("Enter a XML file name: ");
  String xmlFile = bf.readLine();
  File file = new File(xmlFile);
  System.out.print("Enter an element which have to delete: ");
  String remElement = bf.readLine();
  if (file.exists()){
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
  TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer tFormer = tFactory.newTransformer();
  Element element = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName(remElement).item(0);
//  Remove the node
  element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
//  Normalize the DOM tree to combine all adjacent nodes
  doc.normalize();
  Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
  Result dest = new StreamResult(System.out);
  tFormer.transform(source, dest);
  System.out.println();

  }
  else{
  System.out.println("File not found!");
  }
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  System.err.println(e);
  System.exit(0);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code that tries to save the modified file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM is changed in process memory only. There's nothing in code you shown which would write data to the underlying XML file transparently.

You need to add something like

```
createOutputFile("output.xml", transformToString(document));

private static String transformToString(Document document) {
    try {
        TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(buffer));
        return buffer.toString();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


private static void createOutputFile(String filePath, String content) {
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(filePath);
            writer.write(content);
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.flush();
                writer.close(); 
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the TFormer.transform also on the OutputStream of the file

Answer (score 0):

after removing a node from xml, write the content into xml file

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  InputSource is = new InputSource();
  is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));

  Document doc = db.parse(is);


// write the content into xml file

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

after writing the content to xml file the xml file get updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        String filepath = "/java/CarsNEW.xml"; //according to yuor path and file name
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```